# use mysqlbinlog command can't find file

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqlbinlog

when I use mysqlbinlog command I can't find the file.

```
 lihaodeMacBook-Pro:data lihao$ mysqlbinlog --start-position=106 --stop-position=125  mysqlbin.000001 > ~/tmp1.sql
    mysqlbinlog: File 'mysql-bin.000001' not found (Errcode: 13)
lihaodeMacBook-Pro:data lihao$ ls -a
        .                            ib_logfile0                  library                      mysql-bin.000001
        ..                           ib_logfile1                  lihaodeMacBook-Pro.local.err mysql-bin.000002
        lihaodeMacBook-Pro:data lihao$ mysqlbinlog /usr/local/mysql-5.1.63-osx10.6-x86_64/data/mysql-bin.000001
        /*!40019 SET @@session.max_insert_delayed_threads=0*/;
        /*!50003 SET @OLD_COMPLETION_TYPE=@@COMPLETION_TYPE,COMPLETION_TYPE=0*/;
        DELIMITER /*!*/;
        mysqlbinlog: File '/usr/local/mysql-5.1.63-osx10.6-x86_64/data/mysql-bin.000001' not found (Errcode: 13)
```

Comment: First thanks for your helps.But I had try to specifying a path or execute the mybinlog in the folder where my binlogs are,but it still can't find. Do you now what is the path for binlogs on oxs.

Comment: I find the solution.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I find the solution of the question by myself.I can't find the file because I don't have permission to read or write the file.I can use the command by add sudo at front of the commend.

Comment: Me too.  I had to do like "sudo -u mysql mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.000001".  mysqlbinlog(1) without some options just reads the file statically so that read-permission on the OS file system level is required.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Server 5.7 issue resolved:
there are two possibilities over here.

One is either your bin-log file is in `/var/log/mysql` in that case:

```
cd /var/log/mysql/
```

then access the file as sudo user

```
sudo mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.00000x
```

if file is in `/var/lib/mysql` then one needs sudo access to even read the file so follow these two steps:

Login as sudo root user

```
sudo -i
```

Once u are sudo user then go to the following directory: (without being a sudo user this location will deny the permission to even enter the directory)

```
cd /var/lib/mysql/
```

after that access the file

```
sudo mysqlbinlog mysql-bin.00000x
```

Comment: to just know the location mysql bin-log file enter mysql and type mysql> show variables like "%log_bin%";

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was permission related. Ensure you're sudo when using `mysqlbinglong` utility.

Should somebody submit an issue to the creators of the `mysqlbinlog` utility ? The error should be a bit more clear in my opinion.